# Symbolic Link Issue Extracting Tarball on Windows

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, tar

I am having an issue with extracting [this gzipped tarball](https://libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz) (direct link) on Windows platform. The problem is that the tarball contains symbolic links & the <del>Windows platform</del> (tar utility I have on the Windows platform) does not know how to handle them.

I am using GNU Tar under the the [MSYS2/MinGW-w64](http://www.msys2.org/) environment. Extracting the archive results in the following error message:

```
$ tar -xf SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/OpusFile.framework/Resources: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Resources’: No such file or directory

tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/OpusFile.framework/Headers: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Headers’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/OpusFile.framework/OpusFile: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/OpusFile’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Vorbis.framework/Vorbis: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Vorbis’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Vorbis.framework/Resources: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Resources’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Vorbis.framework/Headers: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Headers’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Ogg: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Ogg’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Resources: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Resources’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Headers: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Headers’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/modplug.framework/modplug: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/modplug’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/modplug.framework/Resources: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Resources’: No such file or directory tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/modplug.framework/Headers: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Headers’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/mpg123.framework/mpg123: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/mpg123’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/mpg123.framework/Resources: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Resources’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/mpg123.framework/Headers: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Headers’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/FLAC.framework/Resources: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Resources’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/FLAC.framework/FLAC: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/FLAC’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/FLAC.framework/Headers: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Headers’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Opus.framework/Opus: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Opus’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Opus.framework/Resources: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Resources’: No such file or directory
tar: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/Opus.framework/Headers: Cannot create symlink to ‘Versions/Current/Headers’: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

$ echo $?
2
```

Because I am using this command in a script, the return value of the `tar` command dictates whether or not the script should exit in failure.

```
tar -xf SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
RET=$?
if test ${RET} -ne 0; then
    echo "An error occurred during extraction. Exiting ..."
    exit ${RET}
fi
```

GNU Tar has the `-h|--dereference` switch, but this is only for compressing, not extracting.

I can currently get around the issue by excluding the "Xcode" directory (which is only used on MacOS anyway, I believe) with the following command:

```
$ tar --exclude="SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/Xcode" -xf SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
```

But if there is a way to keep the "Xcode" directory intact & convert the symbolic links to regular files, I would prefer to do that.

Using 7zip to extract the tarball I receive a similar error:

```
$ "/c/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" x -y SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
...

$ "/c/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" x -y SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar
...
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\OpusFile.framework\Resources
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\OpusFile.framework\Headers
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\OpusFile.framework\OpusFile
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\OpusFile.framework\Versions\Current
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Vorbis.framework\Vorbis
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Vorbis.framework\Resources
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Vorbis.framework\Headers
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Vorbis.framework\Versions\Current
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Ogg.framework\Ogg
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Ogg.framework\Resources
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Ogg.framework\Headers
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Ogg.framework\Versions\Current
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\modplug.framework\modplug
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\modplug.framework\Resources
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\modplug.framework\Headers
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\modplug.framework\Versions\Current
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\mpg123.framework\mpg123
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\mpg123.framework\Resources
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\mpg123.framework\Headers
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\mpg123.framework\Versions\Current
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\FLAC.framework\Resources
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\FLAC.framework\FLAC
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\FLAC.framework\Headers
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\FLAC.framework\Versions\Current
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Opus.framework\Opus
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Opus.framework\Resources
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Opus.framework\Headers
ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : .\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4\Xcode\Frameworks\Opus.framework\Versions\Current
...
```

There is an [alternative zip archive](https://libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.zip) (direct link) that I could use instead, but tarballs are very common on non-Windows platforms & I would like to learn how to get past this issue for future reference.

**Update: 2022-06-18**

From the [answer by jigwan](https://superuser.com/a/1483203/894388) & comment by Eric Gopak, it appears that 7-zip can handle converting the symbolic links using the built-in Windows `mklink` command. However, `mklink` requires elevated privileges or for developer mode to be enabled on the Windows system. This may not be a feasible solution for users without administrative privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Windows can handle symbolic links just fine (see the [mklink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command). I have the same problem when I try to extract using GNU tar on Windows 10. However, 7-Zip can handle it just fine if I am running the terminal as Administrator (or run the 7-Zip GUI as Administrator).

```
$ /c/Program\ Files/7-Zip/7z.exe x SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar.gz
...

$ /c/Program\ Files/7-Zip/7z.exe x -oSDL2_mixer_7z/ SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar

7-Zip 18.06 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-12-30

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 45209600 bytes (44 MiB)

Extracting archive: SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar
--
Path = SDL2_mixer-2.0.4.tar
Type = tar
Physical Size = 45209600
Headers Size = 1409536
Code Page = UTF-8

Everything is Ok

Folders: 283
Files: 2432
Size:       43182017
Compressed: 45209600
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me too! It makes sense that it requires running as Administrator, since `mklink` also requires the admin privileges

Comment: How can it be done without elevated privileges or enabling developer mode?